# iphone multiple uitableview in one view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any sample project which shows multiple `UITableView` functionality?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Comment: This is a fairly un-common set up, as you (usually) only activate a cell within one UITableView at a time, hence you could use a UITableView with multiple sections to provide the illusion of "multiple" tables. What are you attempting to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this Sample project, but you need to have an account to download it:

[Multiple table views on a single screen](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/attachments/iphone-sdk-development/29d1220809715-multiple-table-views-single-screen-nothing-showing-up-testtableviewcontroller.zip)

The idea is very simple all you need to do is to distinguish between the `UITableView` that will trigger the delegates, for example:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
  if (tableView == tableView1)
  {
    [FirstDataSource count];
  }
  else if (tableView == tableView2)
  {
    [SecondeDataSource count];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my blog post on this topic: http://iappexperience.com/post/23157217438/how-to-add-multiple-uitableviews-in-the-same-view.

Basically you can create a (second) UITableView and put it in the header (or wherever fits your scenario) of another UITableView. Then create a UITableViewController and hook it up with the UITableView in the header.